# How to deploy windows 8 Metro app package on to a Surface RT tablet?

Tags: windows-8, microsoft-metro, winrt-xaml, windows-rt

I am developing a C#/XAML METRO Application I created the package which generated the `Add-AppDevPackage.ps1` and all other files from VS2012 but:

I wanted to know how to deploy this package in real device for testing in Surface RT tablet?

Answer (score 3):

Option 1: Take that folder containing the .appx file and copy it to wherever you need to deploy it. then right click on the .ps1 script and select "run with powershell", which will install the package on the other machine

Option 2: download the remote debugging for visual studio onto the other pc and run it. Then from your visual studio machine select "remote machine" and select the other pc from there

Answer (score 0):

I found this link while searching for the same information as the OP:
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/spike/archive/2013/05/20/how-to-deploy-your-windows-store-app-to-surface-rt-for-testing.aspx

Hopefully this is helpful to someone who comes across this post.  Basically, you will need to build the packages and copy them to the device, and then get your developer license installed on the device as well.

Complete instructions in the linked article.

One issue I came across was at the "Run with PowerShell" of the `.ps1` file, I was getting signing certificate errors.  I had to manually install the `.cer` file, and you have to make sure to put it in **Certificates (Local Computer) > Trusted Root Certification Authorities > Certificates** node or the **Certificates (Local Computer) > Trusted People > Certificates** node for the signing certificate to be trusted by Windows and allow you to install your app package.